# How to add the AppTrackingTransparency permission to your iOS apps

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, ads, ios14

I am extremely new to iOS, with no iOS development experience at all, however, I've been given a task that's related to `preparing for iOS 14+`. Based on what I've found https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/9997589, to ensure there's no loss in revenue, I need to do 2 things.

1. Install the latest Google Mobile Ads SDK for iOS (version 7.64 or later) for AdMob or Ad Manager
2. Add the AppTrackingTransparency permission to your iOS apps.

I've followed some guides and I'm at the point of dealing with adding the `AppTrackingTransparency permission` to the iOS app. This is the guide that I'm using, https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14#swift.

I managed to add the key/value, shown below, in `Info.plist`

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you.</string>
```

But this is where I'm hoping to get some help. I think that I still need to add code somewhere to request user permission with AppTrackingTransparency. Based on the guide I think the following code is required to show the `App Tracking Transparency dialog box`. `Question 1`, is my assumption correct?

```
import AppTrackingTransparency
import AdSupport
...
func requestIDFA() {
  ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
    // Tracking authorization completed. Start loading ads here.
    // loadAd()
  })
}
```

`Question 2`, does the code live in `AppDelegate.swift`? Or is it really just somewhere that's suitable in the codebase? Thanks.

Comment: 1. The usage description appears as part of the App Tracking Transparency dialog once you add the key in info.plist. No Need to add any special code for that.

2. You can add the code to any of your view controller on which you want to show the ADs. If you add in Appdelegate it will show the Ads once you launch the application itself.

Comment: do we have to code when the user accepts/denies permission? or the OS does it for the app? For example, do we have to disable analytics manually if user denies permission?

Answer (score 71):

For those who might be struggling with the same things, I got the AppTrackingTransparency dialog box to appear with the function,

```
import AppTrackingTransparency
import AdSupport

//NEWLY ADDED PERMISSIONS FOR iOS 14
func requestPermission() {
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                // Tracking authorization dialog was shown
                // and we are authorized
                print("Authorized")
                
                // Now that we are authorized we can get the IDFA
                print(ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier)
            case .denied:
                // Tracking authorization dialog was
                // shown and permission is denied
                print("Denied")
            case .notDetermined:
                // Tracking authorization dialog has not been shown
                print("Not Determined")
            case .restricted:
                print("Restricted")
            @unknown default:
                print("Unknown")
            }
        }
    }
}
//
```

I then simply called the function `requestPermission()` on the app's login page, so users see the permission dialog before signing in. Without calling the function, the dialog box show in this guide, https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14, doesn't appear for me.

This article has an example github project: https://medium.com/@nish.bhasin/how-to-get-idfa-in-ios14-54f7ea02aa42

Comment: For those using react native, you can call the ATTrackingManager function using the react-native-permissions package by:

import { PERMISSIONS, RESULTS, request } from 'react-native-permissions';

onst handleAppStateChange = async (nextAppState) => {
    if (nextAppState == 'active') {
      request(PERMISSIONS.IOS.APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY)
        .then(async (result) => {
          if (result == RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          // do something
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('error: ', error);
        });
    }

Answer (score 35):

## Your complete guide to ATT (updated for iOS 15)

### tl;dr

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
            switch status {
                case .authorized:
                    print("enable tracking")
                case .denied:
                    print("disable tracking")
                default:
                    print("disable tracking")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Long answer

All new apps submitted to the App Store need to follow [App Tracking Transparency](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency?language=swift) guidelines in iOS 14.0+. These guidelines form part of new [Apple privacy guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-privacy-details/). The main idea is for users to be given control of whether all apps can track them, some apps can track them, and make the privacy policies of the apps **Transparent** on download. :+1: Apple :wink:

#### 1. Add framework in Xcode

This is possible by navigating to `<PROJECT_NAME>.xcproject / <PROJECT_NAME>.xcworkspace -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`.

[image: General Xcode Tab with ATT.framework]

#### 2. Add `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription`

This is a String key that needs to be added to `Info.plist`/ the Xcode project's `Information` tab (.xcodeproj or .xcworkspace files).

#### 3. `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:`

This function is advised on the **first app launch** to ensure the value is captured. The prompt only shows if the app is a fresh install and the user consent status is unknown.

For the majority of applications, only enable tracking if the status is authorized on becoming active (new in iOS 15), as below:

```
import AppTrackingTransparency

class AppDelegate: UIApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
                switch status {
                    case .authorized:
                        print("enable tracking")
                    case .denied:
                        print("disable tracking")
                    default:
                        print("disable tracking")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: UI Logic needs to be wrapped on the `DispatchQueue.main` queue because the completion block currently executes on a concurrent `DispatchQueue`.

#### 4. `ATTrackingManager.trackingAuthorizationStatus`

Track changes to consent via `ATTrackingManager.trackingAuthorizationStatus` which has [4 possible enum values](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency/attrackingmanagerauthorizationstatus?language=swift):

1. `ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` - Granted consent.
2. `ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusDenied` - Denied consent.
3. `ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` - Unknown consent.
4. `ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusRestricted` - Device has an MDM solution applied. Recommend handling this the same as consent denied until vendor provides consent explicitly.

#### 5. Track the user's consent status on internal servers

If you are capturing your own analytics, this step is necessary because the user can toggle consent at any time using iOS Settings.

### 3rd-Party Analytics

#### Recommendation

It's safer to disable `Firebase Analytics`, `Flurry Analytics`, or other Analytics providers from the configuration on app launch after reading the status value when consent is denied/restricted.

#### Reasoning

1. Even if the frameworks don't track users for the moment, the SDKs may update and alter their policies down the line, and your code will not be synced automatically.
2. There are lots of nuances in the Apple privacy legislation, and it's better to avoid the risk of getting store blacklisted IMHO.
3. Technically you can hide from the [Apple privacy guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-privacy-details/), but do you want to get exposed when they start [verifying the accuracy](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=n5jlz7ox) of your App Store statements? This could lead to **permanent blacklisting**.

#### Example [Firebase policy](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5928#issuecomment-650332162) (26.06.20)

> To answer your questions:
>
> - No, Analytics will not access the ad ID if no advertising SDKs are present and `AdSupport` is not linked. However, `SafariServices` on
>   iOS 11 imports the `AdSupport` framework, causing device advertisement
>   identifier reporting. #1686 (GH issue #) makes it so that explicit ad
>   ID access control is required, which is something we need to add on
>   the Firebase side.
> - Yes, if you're using Analytics with an ad framework you should follow Apple's guidelines. You may not be able to submit to the App
>   Store otherwise.

#### Other Option

SO, *yes* it is possible to work around declaring whether you use analytics, but I don’t advise it.

To be honest, I prefer App Store Analytics over 3rd Party Analytics going forward for an integrated experience over more tracking. However, many companies heavily rely on 3rd party analytics data, and if you aren't able to migrate away, transparently declare your analytics usage.

Another ideal strategy would be to fully revamp or rapidly A/B test the app before launching live - use beta modes. Analytics in the App Store is more than enough for live apps.

I can't quantify the risk for being blacklisted subsequently though, as this is library-specific and also depends on your release workflow (do you check for changes in SDK policies?).

### Important Note

Wrap

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *)
```

Wherever you call the `ATTrackingManager` because the request will not complete on older iOS versions . Track consent on older iOS versions with your own backend flags, or locally on the device.

Apple suggests implementing the new ATT requirements as soon as possible if you track users because you will be blocked from new updates to the App Store in the meantime, even with production crashes. Not only will your users be happier, but your App Store ranking improves if you update your app regularly.

Want to toggle user consent in the app? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67596403/enable-user-to-toggle-app-tracking-consent-status-within-ios-app/67596404) for more info.

Comment: Do you know when will TrackingAuthorizationStatus will be "restricted"?

Comment: What is the difference between "restricted" and "denied"?

Comment: I think “restricted” should be treated the same as “denied”. I believe a restricted device has an MDM solution applied, so the device doesn’t ask for consent - more details [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mdm/mdm0f7dd3d8/web).

Comment: I don't think you need to turn off FirebaseAnalytics if tracking was denied. This tracking is used to link user's online activity across apps and web-browsing, to be able to identify him and serve targeted ads. FirebaseAnalytics has nothing to do with this. Only if you specifically track his activity like "searched_nike_shoes_size_42" and also assign an ID, and then sell this data to a DataBroker.

Comment: @Starsky not necessarily, have a look at [Google’s](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5928) official response.

Answer (score 34):

In **iOS 15** it can only be requested with `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` if the application state is already active, so it should be moved from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Answer (score 5):

We are using Firebase and Facebook, to get the app approved we put both calls "behind" the ATT protection, that is:

For Facebook (from AppDelegate):

```
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
    ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
        if status == .authorized {
                ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
                    application,
                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
                )
        }
    }
}
```

For Firebase:

```
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
    ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
        if status == .authorized {
            Analytics.logEvent(eventName, parameters: [:])
        }
    }
}
```

As for the firebase token for the notifications, we did not include them behind the protection and had no issue.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` in the App Delegate `applicationDidBecomeActive` function won't be called if you're using **Scenes**  because of [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622956-applicationdidbecomeactive) instead use `sceneDidBecomeActive(_:)` in the **SceneDelegate** and make sure you delay for a second else it won't be called for some reason.

```
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
        
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
                switch status {
                    case .authorized:
                        print("enable tracking")
                    case .denied:
                        print("disable tracking")
                    default:
                        print("default tracking")
                }
            }
        }
        
    })
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the link you posted:

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14#swift.

The main thing to avoid loss of revenue from AdMob is to add this into Info.plist:

```
<key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
    <string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
  </dict>
</array>
```

I don't know when/if AppTrackingTransparency permission is required. I know Apple say you need it but they don't give a deadline. Google say "If you decide to include App Tracking Transparency" which to me is hinting to not bother!

Answer (score 3):

1. Open `info.plist` file, add `SKAdNetworkIdentifier` and `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription`. The following one is only for Google (Admob), you can find the full list [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14#skadnetwork).

   ```
   <key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
   <array>
       <dict>
           <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
           <string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
       </dict>
   </array>

   //..

   <key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
   <string>This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you.</string>
   ```
2. Request the ATT dialog. *(For simplicity I'm requesting it right after the app loads)*

   ```
   #import <AppTrackingTransparency/AppTrackingTransparency.h>
   #import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>

   //...

   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
       didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

       // ...

       if (@available(iOS 14.0, *))
       {
           [ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:^(ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus status) {
           // Tracking authorization completed. Start loading ads here.
           // [self loadAd];
         }];

     return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
func askPermission() {
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { (status) in
            //handled
            print(status)
            if status == .authorized{
                
                Settings.shared.isAdvertiserTrackingEnabled = true
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know but for me this piece of code works

Answer (score 1):

As a completion on @mark answer you also should add permission statement to plist file in key Privacy - Tracking Usage Description

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that if the following method

"ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler()"

is called from AppDelegate then sometimes "ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined" is returned as a status and an alert is not shown.
My phone's iOS version is "iOS-15.0.2"

As a solution, we can call "requestTrackingAuthorization..." method after splash screen or after appearing LandingPage.

Answer (score 0):

For me embedding the dialog into App Delegate `applicationDidBecomeActive` wasn't working.

I embedded the well known `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` into my **initial viewcontroller**.