# Enable user to toggle App Tracking Consent status within iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, ios14

How can I enable the user to toggle consent easily from within a menu **inside** a live iOS app with the new App Tracking Transparency requirements? I used to track user consent without Apple's ATT requirements via a Checkmark button. Am I allowed to use this consent status still? Can I track consent via a webview instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

No. We can't toggle user consent locally without Apple. i.e., the consent status now for Analytics has a single source of truth ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/)).

### Tracking consent without Apple's Framework

> If I have not received permission from a user via the tracking
> permission prompt, can I use an identifier other than the IDFA (for
> example, a hashed email address or hashed phone number) to track that
> user?
>
> No. You will need to receive the user’s permission through the
> AppTrackingTransparency framework to track that user.

### Tracking consent with a Website instead

> If a user provides permission for tracking via a separate process on
> our website, but declines permission in the app tracking transparency
> prompt, can I track that user across apps and websites owned by other
> companies?
>
> Developers must get permission via the app tracking
> transparency prompt for data that’s collected in the app and used for
> tracking. Data collected separately, outside of the app and not
> related to the app, is not in scope.

## Alternative

The `iOS Settings -> Privacy -> Tracking` menu from within an app is not accessible because URL schemes to Settings were deprecated in iOS 10+.

But you don't need to go that far:

```
if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

The app page in Settings also has the option to toggle consent just for your app. Remember to track your consent status with Apple's consent for **every app launch** since the user can change this value at any time. For more info, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67601694/4995828).