# iOS App Tracking transparency on ionic Apps in InAppbrowser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ios14, inappbrowser, apptrackingtransparency

I have Ionic based app where we load some sites using inappbrowser. The site which we are loading has the cookie popup to accept. When we send app for the review, Apple rejected the build, and below is the reason they send

> Guideline 5.1.2 - Legal - Privacy - Data Use and Sharing We noticed
> you do not use App Tracking Transparency to request the user's
> permission before collecting data used to track them. Instead, your
> app displays a custom prompt that requests the user to allow tracking.
>
> Starting with iOS 14.5, apps on the App Store need to receive the
> user’s permission through the AppTrackingTransparency framework before
> collecting data used to track them. Requesting permission with a
> custom prompt is not appropriate.
>
> Next Steps
>
> If your app collects data in order to track users, you must take the
> following steps:
>
> 1. If you haven't already, update your app privacy information in App Store Connect to disclose that you track users. You must have the
>    Account Holder or Admin role to update app privacy information.
> 2. Implement App Tracking Transparency.
> 3. Remove the custom prompts, and request permission using the AppTrackingTransparency framework before collecting data used to track
>    the user. When you resubmit, indicate in the Review Notes where the
>    permission request is located.
>
> You may also choose to remove the tracking functionality from your
> app, as well as the custom prompts to allow tracking.
>
> Resources
>
> - Tracking is linking data collected from your app with third-party data for advertising purposes or sharing the collected data with a
>   data broker. Learn more about tracking.
> - See Frequently Asked Questions about the requirements for apps that track users.
> - Learn more about designing appropriate permission requests.

The website which we are loading is using google analytics and not tracking any user data or user device data. The website is using google analytics cookies.
Do I really need to implement the App Tracking Transparency Framework? If I do then what if the user selected doesn't allow tracking? What action do I have to perform to work the app within Apple Guideline?
Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: `https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681464` & `https://www.appsflyer.com/blog/tips-strategy/if-when-show-att-prompt/` .. so view these 2 sites

Comment: and if u need to add a native code also check this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587364/how-to-add-the-apptrackingtransparency-permission-to-your-ios-apps`