# AppTrackingTransparency permission dialog doesn't show up

Tags: flutter, ios-permissions

I'm asking for tracking-transparency permission using the [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler/versions/10.2.0) in my app:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
    Permission.photosAddOnly,
    Permission.camera,
    Permission.microphone,
    Permission.appTrackingTransparency,
  ].request();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

All permission dialogs appear except for the `appTrackingTransparency` one.

**Why it doesn't show up?**

flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.7, on macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-x64, locale en-IL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

device version: `iOS 15.2.1`

permission_handler: `10.0.0`

Comment: Which version of iOS in your podFile, in this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587364/how-to-add-the-apptrackingtransparency-permission-to-your-ios-apps) indicates an iOS 14 as a minimum for the dialog box to appear.

Comment: It seems that the MinimumOSVersion of the permission_handler is 9.0

Comment: The podfile `platform :ios {version}` is commented

Comment: The permission_handler documentation does not mention that https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler/versions/10.2.0

Comment: Yes, the handler doesn't indicate that, I'm talking based on the iOS permission. This permission is present only in iOS 14+, try to use this version as a minimum for your podfile.

Comment: But my ios device version is 15.2.1... so it should appear

Answer (score 1):

You must list permission you want to use in your application

Inside your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
      '$(inherited)',
      'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',
      ]
    end 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the [app_tracking_transparency](https://pub.dev/packages/app_tracking_transparency). But the dialog still doesn't show up.

After reading about swift solutions, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69423995/12695188), **adding a minor delay** between dialogs seems to solve it.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await [
    Permission.photosAddOnly,
    Permission.camera,
    Permission.microphone,
  ].request();

  /// Getting permission for appTrackingTransparency required a delay between prompts.
  if (await AppTrackingTransparency.trackingAuthorizationStatus ==
      TrackingStatus.notDetermined) {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    await AppTrackingTransparency.requestTrackingAuthorization();
  }

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Note: I don't know why, but it worked only with the `app_tracking_transparency` package, but not with the `permission_handler` package.

**Still Looking for a better solution, using the permission_handler package, that does not delay the app load time.**